# R display in console two progress bars stacked (with code)

Tags: r, function, console, progress-bar, progress

**IS IT POSSIBLE TO DO THIS? I'd like to display two progress bars at the same time, vertically stacked, in R as a function runs within another larger function.**

One would be for the overall process status of the larger of the function, the other for individual processes within the function (downloads etc.).

1. I'd like to use the progress package's progress_bar's if possible (if not possible, base or whatever solution is cool! :) )
2. I'd like to stay in the console and not plot a progress bar with tk or a solution like this(https://www.r-bloggers.com/multiple-progress-bars/)

Thanks in advance!

**Examples below** of imitated desired functions and outcomes in both progress(preferred) and Base R:

```
 ###Example in progress package(preferred)
library(progress)

###Create the progress bars
overallbar <- progress_bar$new(
  format = " downloading :what [:bar] :percent Guestimated Remaining OVERALL: :eta",
  clear = FALSE, total = 1000, width = 60)
statusbar <- progress_bar$new(
  format = " [:bar] :percent Guestimated Remaining CURRENT FILE: :eta",
  clear = FALSE, total = 100, width = 60)

###Only displays the statusbar when I'd like to display both

for (i in 1:1000) {
  overallbar$tick()
  statusbar$tick()
  Sys.sleep(1 / 1000)
}

###Desired outcome (imitation only)
downloading THIS FILE NOW [] 100% Guestimated remaining OVERALL:  0s
[============] 100% Guestimated remaining CURRENT FILE:  0s
```

**AN EXAMPLE USING BASE R INSTEAD (less desired than progress package style):**

```
###Base R
pb1   <- txtProgressBar(1, 1000, style=3)
pb2   <- txtProgressBar(title="File Progress",1, 100, style=3)


###Like progress, base also only displays the second progress bar 

cat("OVERALL PROGRESS:")
for (i in 1:1000) {
  setTxtProgressBar(pb1, i)
  ###something is funky with the title option, not working
  ###I usually use progress package, you get the idea, I'd like a title
  setTxtProgressBar(title="File Progress:", pb2, i)
  Sys.sleep(1 / 1000)
}

###Desired outcome (imitation only)

OVERALL PROGRESS:
|========================================================================================| 100%
File Progress:
|========================================================================================| 100%
```

Answer (score 2):

At least in the Base R case, progress bars work by simply re-drawing the same line. You can use ANSI escape sequences to jump between lines. Modifying your Base R example,

```
cat("OVERALL PROGRESS:\n\n") # 2 newlines leaving a blank between headers
cat("File Progress:\n") # 1 newline leaves in position for pb2
for (i in 1:1000) {
  cat("\033[2A")   # up 2 lines for pb1
  setTxtProgressBar(pb1, i)
  cat("\033[2B")   # down 2 lines for pb2
  setTxtProgressBar(title="File Progress:", pb2, i)
  Sys.sleep(1 / 1000)
}
cat("\033[2B\n") # for good measure
```

This works in [Linux](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html), probably also MacOS Terminal, and [maybe even Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) although I did not test there.

Comment: Thanks for this! I ended up with something very similar, but using writeLines and clearing the whole console with cat("\014"). . . I'll have to dust off the super old windows computer and test out if yours works on windows. I don't think you can clear the whole console in windows so I doubt mine works in windows, can you go up and down more than a line in windows? I know there are serious limitations.